# Matshita DVD-RAM UJ-841S can't read burned DVD's or CD's

Tags: dvd, compact-disc, sony-vaio

I have a Sony VAIO VGN-FE11S using a Matshita DVD Writable drive. My problem is that a few weeks ago, my drive stopped reading burned DVD's and CD's.  It only reads original DVD's or CD's.  I haven't installed anything.

Has anyone with the same problem been able to resolve this?

**Discinfo summary**

DISCINFO VERSION   : 1.7.0 BETA.12

- VENDOR             : MATSHITA
- MODEL              : DVD-RAM UJ-841S
- REVISION           : 1.11
- VENDOR SPECIFIC    : 601200KME1997131264
- INTERFACE          : ATAPI

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, the drive is starting to die. It might be time to look into getting a replacement. I've had drives before that have stopped burning, but only read. Others only read certain disks. Others gave read errors randomly.

Can you still burn CD/DVD's?

Comment: No can't burn cd's only read originals cd's

Answer (score 1):

I have to deal with this sort of problem quite frequently.

I have not seen this problem on CD or DVD drives that are only used for reading, but when they are used for writing, I seem to see "random" errors from failed writes, down to failed reads after 50-200 writes... It is completely random, but surprisingly low.

I guess that on most of these drives, the laser just doesn't last from long time burning.

FYI, I had to fix recently a Sony that was a similar model to yours. They quoted around £200 for the identical part. If you buy any compatible slim line drive (or sometimes it is cheaper to buy a slimline optical enclosure and rip out the optical drive), you can take out yours and remove all the enclosure (sides, connector at the back and front plate) you can have a replacement for a fraction of the cost.

Comment: I know where i can find this drive for sell in internet? I tried EBAY and not found.

Comment: Not eBay, take a look at any computer shop for a "slimline optical drive".

Answer (score 1):

Some drives are just sensitive to the burn media type. They need either a firmware update, or to be wholly replaced. Alternatively, you need to find the burn media type that is readable in this drive, and use that exclusively.  That implies trial and error.